# TYPO3: EXT:form no confirmation finisher in the editor

Tags: forms, typo3, yaml, typo3-8.x

After using EXT:powermail for all forms I decided to test the new EXT:form that ships with the package. It has some very fine options, and although I was not familiar with .yaml I found my way to have a basic form with all options.

The only thing I could not figure out was how to have the confirmation finisher available in the backend editor ... I add the confirmation manually to the .yaml:

```
myextension/Private/Resources/Private/Forms/contactForm.yaml

finishers:
  -
    options:
      message: 'Thanks for the enquiry.'
    identifier: Confirmation
```

anybody an idea how I can activate the finisher in the backend module ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXT:form provides more finishers than are available in the form editor by default.

The following **form configuration** adds the Confirmation finisher to the form editor inside the backend module:

```
    TYPO3:
      CMS:
        Form:
          prototypes:
            standard:
              # Add Confirmation finisher to form editor:
              formElementsDefinition:
                Form:
                  formEditor:
                    editors:
                      900:
                        selectOptions:
                          50:
                            value: 'Confirmation'
                            label: 'formEditor.elements.Form.finisher.Confirmation.editor.header.label'

              # Allow to override confirmation message in form plugin (content element):
              finishersDefinition:
                Confirmation:
                  FormEngine:
                    label: 'formEditor.element.AdvancedPassword.editor.confirmationLabel.predefinedDefaults'
                    elements:
                      message:
                        label: 'formEditor.elements.Form.finisher.Confirmation.editor.header.label'
                        config:
                          type: 'input'
```

The second part – as labeled – allows an editor to change the confirmation message inside a form plugin.

Comment: I had gotten that much from your form_distribution on github !! great that you share, but I still have some bug... is it possible that renderingOptions -> templateRootPaths on prototype 'standard' interfere ?

Comment: I was not reading well, now I got it where the confirmation message is inserted... in fact I did not understand the tickbox 'Override finisher settings' thanks, great answer !!